# pip3 is pointing to the wrong version of python

Tags: python, pip

I have installed `python3.8` and have found no reference on how to get `pip3` to talk to it on `ubuntu`.  On `macos` I had explicitly installed `pip3.8` and that has been crucial to getting all packages lined up correctly.

`pip3` was installed as follows based on numerous recommendations:

```
    sudo apt-get install python3-pip
```

But it is pointing to `python3.6`:

```
$ pip3 -V
pip 9.0.1 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (python 3.6)
```

Please do not suggest `anaconda` or `venv`: there are reasons we are using directly installed `python3.8`.

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2812520/dealing-with-multiple-python-versions-and-pip

Comment: yes I think the answer will be `python3 -m pip`   . Feel free to make an answer on that

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The best option is to use `python3 -m pip` to run `pip` with a specific python version.

The full docs on this are here: https://packaging.python.org/guides/installing-using-pip-and-virtual-environments/

Comment: Funny thing there's a `pip3.8` for `macOS` : I `brew` installed it. But _not_ for `ubuntu`: so I needed to do the `python3 -m pip` for the latter.