# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils.util' after upgrading to Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: python, python3, pip

After upgrading to Ubuntu 20.04 I started receiving this error

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils.util'
> for every `pip` command I run.

I tried the solutions on [ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils.util'](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1239829/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-distutils-util) and [pip3 is pointing to the wrong version of python](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1223290/pip3-is-pointing-to-the-wrong-version-of-python) but nothing seems to be working.

Tried this:

```
python3 -m pip
```

and:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-distutils
sudo apt-get install python3-apt
```

these two commands are telling me these packages are already installed, so I reintalled them but no light at the end of the tunnel.

Any solution for this?

I have a virtual environment running Python 3.6.9.

Comment: removed in `python 3.12` . See complete answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76691103/13086128

Answer (score 11):

In my case, I solved this with

```
sudo apt install python3.10-distutils
```

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this by installing the version-specific distutils:

i.e.:

```
sudo apt install python3.9-apt
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try solving it by installing your version of `distutils`, as you are running Python 3.6.9:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt install python3.6-distutils
```

Comment: I'd note that you need to trust the source of the ppa as you'll be giving them sudo access on install. Bionic has [distutils](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=any&keywords=python3-distutils&searchon=names) 3.6.9, which may be better than using a random ppa.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by creating a new virtual environment running Python 3.8.